# Adjust the offset of two nearly same images with python

Tags: python, opencv, imagemagick

i am trying to find the differences in two pictures from a newspaper riddle. I cut the contours with opencv and create two images which have nearly the same size. So to find the difference i would like to get the offset of the images. It would be great to use a python script for this. Here are two example pictures for this.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rVtO.jpg)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHMz.jpg)

How can i find the offset of the two pictures with python?

BR kami

I search on the internet and tested some modules and functions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: see phase correlation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/df3/group__imgproc__motion.html#ga552420a2ace9ef3fb053cd630fdb4952

Comment: Please post your solution

Comment: I just tested it. And it is working, but i decided to use just an easy resize of both pics to the same size.